# How to install redkite CMS with Web-Installer interface

Tags: symfony, symfony-1.4, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.3

I am new to the symfony framework.  I want to install redkite symfony cms with web installer interface.  I have downloaded the interface from github but don't have an idea how to use it.
Can anyone tell me how to use it?

Comment: Read http://redkite-labs.com/download-redkite-cms-sandbox ??? There's everything you need to install Redkite

Comment: yes i have read this and i have installed it as per document but its giving me 404  Not Found - NotFoundHttpException .